# Getting ModelState Error using AngularJs (ASP.NET WebApi)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I'm trying to create a registration form with unique usernames. I set up the API and tested it with Postman and it gives the expected results when I try to create 2 users with the same username. But when I try to display the error to the user using AngularJs, nothing get's displayed

```
EDIT: ADDED MORE CODE
```

**My Angular Code**

**An authService that contains the saveRegistration function**

```
  var _saveRegistration = function (registration) {
    _logout();
    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'api/create',registration)

    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    );
};
```

**Then a signupCtrl that uses the service**

```
$scope.signup = function () {
    authService.saveRegistration($scope.registration).then(function (response) {
        $scope.savedSuccessfully = true;
    },
     function (response) {
         var errors = [];
         for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
             for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                 errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
             }
         }
         $scope.message = errors;
     });
};
```

**My Html View**

```
<ul >
   <li data-ng-repeat="messages in message">
       {{messages}}
   <li>
</ul>
```

Can someone please help point me to the right direction here

Comment: are you able to provide the ajax call function or check if the ajax call hot the response function above ? Also the response output.

Comment: can you post the code which shows how and from where you are calling that `function(response){...}`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary sorry for the late reply. I've added more of the code I used when trying this out

Comment: @kwan245 sorry for the late reply. I've updated the question with more of the code i used

Comment: you are using the then method so function response is only invoked if http post is successful. Are you able to check if the post message is returning status code 200/201 ? You also can try to supply both success & error method for then method.